# wordpress : how to add commas between meta terms on single custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, meta

extendeing may last question about how to change the display of meta on single custom post type, with a great thanks to TimRDD for his helpful answer, now i have another question.
the working generating code

```
<?php
//get all taxonomies and terms for this post (uses post's post_type)
foreach ( (array) get_object_taxonomies($post->post_type) as $taxonomy ) {
  $object_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'all'));
  if ($object_terms) {
    echo '- '.$taxonomy;
foreach ($object_terms as $term) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $term->name.'</a> ';
}
    }
  }
}
?>
```

displays the terms in a single row but without commas between them such as :
(- Proceeding2015 - keywordsbusinessconsumerresearch).

I need your help please to put (:) after every set of terms and commas between terms to display them such as :
(- proceeding : 2015 - keywords : business, consumer, research).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code is ok, you just need to modify the output a bit. Try this code:

```
//get all taxonomies and terms for this post (uses post's post_type)
foreach ((array) get_object_taxonomies($post->post_type) as $taxonomy) {
    $object_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'all'));
    if ($object_terms) {
        echo ': (- ' . $taxonomy . ': ';// I modify the output a bit.
        $res = '';
        foreach ($object_terms as $term) {
            $res .= '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf(__("View all posts in %s"), $term->name) . '" ' . '>' . $term->name . '</a>, ';
        }
        echo rtrim($res,' ,').')';// I remove the last trailing comma and space and add a ')'
    }
}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: please is there any way to make the code display the terms of a specific taxonomy (such as keyword) and not all the terms from all taxonomies? i tried to replace fields' => 'all' with fields' => 'keyword' but it didn't work!! any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this code, but I have linted it. Based on your description, this should do it.

```
<?php
//get all taxonomies and terms for this post (uses post's post_type)
```

I moved this out of the `fornext`.

```
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post->post_type);

foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
```

I moved this into an `if` statement. If the assignment fails (nothing is returned) it should fail the `if` and skip all of this.

```
    if ($object_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'all'))) {

        $holding = array();

        foreach ($object_terms as $term) {
```

Instead of outputting it immediately, I am building an array.

```
            $holding[] = '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $term->name.'</a> ';

        } // foreach ($object_terms as $term)
```

Here is where we do that output. I'm using the `explode()` function. This will output each element of the array and put a ', ' after all of them except for the last one.

```
        echo '- '.$taxonomy . ': ' .explode(', ',$holding) . ' ';

    } // if ($object_terms)

} // foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy )

?>
```

I do hope I got it right.

Cheers!

=C=